# Tornado application layout. Options.

Tags: python, tornado

Right now I have tornado options in same file, as in tornado app. And they defined like:

```
import tornado.options
tornado.options.define(<name>, default=<value>)
```

Is there way to move them out to separate file?

And also, options accessed by default like this:

```
tornado.options.options.<name>
```

Is there any way to access them just like `settings.<name>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is pretty good for Tornado.

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/options.html

> The main() method of your application does not need to be aware of all of the options used throughout your program; they are all automatically loaded when the modules are loaded. Your main() method can parse the command line or parse a config file with:
>
> ```
> import tornado.options
> tornado.options.parse_config_file("/etc/server.conf")
> tornado.options.parse_command_line()
> ```

Comment: Wow. Got it. Options defined across the application and stored in one *.conf file. I've tried to copy django settings, following my habits. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a conf file, you can simply define them in another file (e.g. settings.py), and import that file.

so, settings.py:

```
import tornado.options
tornado.options.define(<name>, default=<value>)
```

somewhere else:

```
import settings
from tornado.options import options
```

Importing with `from tornado.options import options` lets you get the value with `options.<name>`

Comment: I see, that I was confused. Yes, we can do `from tornado.options import options as opt`.